# Performance comparison of ESM class with a large static constant

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In a browser extension environment, for an ESM `class` with a large `static` constant, is there any **performance** difference (or other pro/con) between having the string inside or outside of the exported `class`?
What about [Private static fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)?

- In the 1st code, `value` is also exported, but everything is encapsulated within one `object`
- In the 2nd code, `value` is not exported, but no encapsulation
- In the 3rd code, `value` is private (Firefox 90+, Chrome 74+)

**module.js**

```js
export class Test {

  static run() {
    // some code using `value`
  }

  static value = '... a very long 90+kb string ...';
}
```

**--- vs ---**

```js
export class Test {

  static run() {
    // some code using `value`
  }
}
const value = '... a very long 90+kb string ...';
```

**--- vs ---**

```js
export class Test {

  static run() {
    // some code using `value`
  }

  static #value = '... a very long 90+kb string ...';
}
```

Comment: The second `value` is still encapsulated because it's not exported. Only `Test` can use it.

Comment: @Kokodoko I understand, and in fact I am using no 2 but in no 2, two variables are created `Test` & `value` in the module whereas in no 1 & 3, only `Test`. In any case, is there any pro/cons for one over the other? (besides older browser support in private fields)

Comment: I don’t think that matters at all, as long as you don’t create new instances that each get a copy of value. But you already solve that by using static. Personally I’d prefer the second option because it’s the simplest.